# Use special fonts on a non-hosted Wordpress blog

Tags: css

I would like to use a font I've paid from webtype.com on my wordpress blog. I don't own the blog so I can't change anything in the main php files as function.php or add any plugins. So, the only solution I've found is to add this content in the css customization file :

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "Scout Normal";
 src: url("http://the/url/of/the/file") format("woff");
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.block p {
 font-family: "Scout Normal";
}
```

The problem is that every time I save the file, Wordpress remove the url in the loading of the font, that means

```
src: url("http://the/url/of/the/file") format("woff");
```

become

```
src: format("woff");
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsKLt.png) to show you where I add those css rules.

Do you have any ideas to force the loading of the font, or an other idea to load it ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should probably talk to your host: it sounds like that theme customisation mechanism is deliberately stripping this out, likely so that you can't e.g. load inappropriate images as CSS backgrounds. Can you talk to them about it? They may be happy to sort this out for you, either as an exception to their filter or as a plugin: you can't be the only one who wants a custom font! As a last resort you could try pasting the base64-encoded font data into your CSS as a data URL, but not all browsers will support that. As a final thought, does your font source server have CORS cross-domain headers?

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to contact them, it's a good idea indeed.

Answer (score 1):

@Clemzd

First off you `@font-face` css is missing a few lines that are required for a font to work correctly across all browsers and platforms.

You only have one src url in your `@font-face` css.

Take a look at how my `@font-face` css is written. My font files are inside a folder called fonts inside the folder of my child theme where I have WP installed on my server.

```
@font-face {
font-family: Antenna-Regular;
src: url('/fonts/Antenna-Regular.eot');
src: url('/fonts/Antenna-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/Antenna-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/Antenna-Regular.otf') format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/Antenna-Regular.svg#Antenna-Regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

If you have the font files locally, why not create a new folder in your child theme called fonts and put the needed files in there. Then make your `@font-face` css look similar to mine.

If the fonts are on webtype.com and they give you the option to use the `@import url(http://link_to_font);` feature, try it out. Just put that line of code near the top of your css stylesheet. Then just use `font-family: nameoffont;` where ever you want in your css.

Comment: Hi, your second solution doesn't work, it's seems the import is not realize. Thank you

Comment: @Clemzd Yes that font site may not have the option to import your fonts like I mentioned. I know google fonts does though.